# How often does data.stackexchange.com data synchronize?

Tags: support, data-explorer, synchronization

I was running some queries just to test the site and the returns do not seem to reflect my activity at all. E.g., ["How Unsung am I?"](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/345/how-unsung-am-i?UserId=542701) query tells me that I have 2 answers on SO, with one scored and one unscored. Same with other queries.
I'm using my SO user id on the box (542701).

Am I doing something else wrong?

BTW, I hesitated to post this question here (I don't know if it's on-topic), but data.SE does not have any commenting options and there are other questions related to data.SE here.

Comment: will be updated ... probably this week

Comment: OK. Thanks. No rush on my part, I was just curious

Answer (score 7):

On the main page of Data Explorer - https://data.stackexchange.com/ you got listed dates of latest available posts. Today I see that for almost all StackExchange sites this is 2011-03-21.

On, relatively recent, [StackOverflow blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/creative-commons-data-dump-apr-11/) it's states that

> (...) use the Stack Exchange Data Explorer,
> which will continue to be updated
> monthly.

which suggest that should be some update, but I suppose that there is important reason for delay.

Comment: My question is here because the data does not seem to reflect my activity at all. And I don't think it reflects anyone's. Try using the user "1" and see.

Comment: If the database shows `2015-04-09 23:44:16Z` is that the moment synchronization *started*, *ended*, or the timestamp of the *last event* that was synchronized?

Answer (score 1):

Note that there's an RSS feed for getting notified of updates:

- http://www.clearbits.net/feeds/creator/146-stack-overflow-data-dump.rss

(as seen on https://data.stackexchange.com/about.)

Thant way, you can just relax and wait for notification when there's new data to explore.

Comment: This RSS is about data dumps available over torrent and not about http://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Marek — do they not correspond?

Comment: According to [post on stack blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/creative-commons-data-dump-apr-11/) I think not. Citing: "(...) you can expect dumps every two months instead of every month. If you have an urgent need for more timely data than this, (...) use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/), which will continue to be updated monthly."

Comment: Huh. Okay then. Thanks. (So much for relaxing. \*grin\*)

Comment: In fact, the data seems to be much older than that, or perhaps only partially synced.