# data.stackexchange.com fresh data

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

This question as been ask before [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89760/how-often-does-data-stackexchange-com-data-synchronize) by Aleadam and answered by Marek. I am sorry I am asking again but the answer is from May.

Should data.stackexchange.com be updated more frequently?

- every week?
- every 2 weeks?

Thank you very much

Comment: Is there a reason to think the answer is wrong now?

Comment: Well maybe I should ask something different, I updated my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're after something specialized, see if the [API](https://stackapps.com/questions/1/api-documentation-and-help) will suit your needs.  It allows you to access the current data, albeit with some rate limits.

There's a [help](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/help) document for the SO version that gives more details, and there are versions that can be used for any site except StackExchange.com and Area51.

Comment: That is more what I am looking for thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why?

The data is **always** out of date - this is simply a consequence of the way the data explorer works (it queries against the data dumps rather than the live database).

Given that its always going to be out of date, what benefit is there to having the data being at most 1 week out of date (for example) as opposed to at most 1 month out of date?

Comment: Well, 1 day out of date is better than 1 year out of date, surely? So why wouldn't 1 week be better than 1 month?

Comment: @Widor If the data was 1 year out of date then it significantly reduces the usefulness of the site if you want to use it for looking at recent trends (e.g. how has X changed over the past year).  Yes 1 day out of date is much better for such queries, but 1 month out of date is *almost* as good while being a **lot** less effort to keep updated.  I've just shown why once a year is too infreuquent, now I'm asking why is once a month too infrequent?

Comment: Because I like the fact you can query data and not ask anyone